# XML XPath Expression to Return Children with Similar Attributes

Tags: xml, xpath, expression

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Job>
        <InvoiceNumber>23456/1.3</InvoiceNumber>
        <CompanyName>DummyJobOne</CompanyName>
        <CompanyNumber>7641</CompanyNumber>
          <Parts>
            <Part>
                <PartNumber>23456/1</PartNumber>
                <SourceEstimate>41847</SourceEstimate>
            </Part>
            <Part>
                <PartNumber>23456/2</PartNumber>
                <SourceEstimate>41847</SourceEstimate>
            </Part>             
            <Part>
                <PartNumber>23456/3.2</PartNumber>
                <SourceEstimate>41847</SourceEstimate>
            </Part>             
            <Part>
                <PartNumber>23459/1</PartNumber>
                <SourceEstimate>41847</SourceEstimate>
            </Part>
            <Part>
                <PartNumber>23459/6</PartNumber>
                <SourceEstimate>41847</SourceEstimate>
            </Part>
         </Parts>
<Job>
```

I would like to create a XPath Expression that will select only the 'Part' where the 'PartNumber' before the /  matches the 'InvoiceNumber' before the /.

In other words, only keep the 'Part' that contain 23456 and remove the 23459 ones.  The outcome should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Job>
        <InvoiceNumber>23456/1.3</InvoiceNumber>
        <CompanyName>DummyJobOne</CompanyName>
        <CompanyNumber>7641</CompanyNumber>
          <Parts>
            <Part>
                <PartNumber>23456/1</PartNumber>
                <SourceEstimate>41847</SourceEstimate>
            </Part>
            <Part>
                <PartNumber>23456/2</PartNumber>
                <SourceEstimate>41847</SourceEstimate>
            </Part>             
            <Part>
                <PartNumber>23456/3.2</PartNumber>
                <SourceEstimate>41847</SourceEstimate>
            </Part>             
         </Parts>
<Job>
```

I apologize in advance for any incorrect terminology or general Buffoonery.
Thanks!

Comment: Your outcome cannot be achieved via XPath alone.  XPath is for selection; you need transformation.  Consider using XSLT.

Comment: If i use the expression: 
    /Job/Parts/Part[PartNumber=/Job/InvoiceNumber]/PartNumber   I can isolate exact matches to the 'InvoiceNumber'.  Is there no way to have it ignore the /and everything after it?

Comment: Sure, you can use `substring-before()` to help you select the targeted `Part` elements, but with XPath alone you cannot reassemble the selected parts in the context of the ancestral elements shown in your desired outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`XPath`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) is only to select elements in xml. You can't expect some elements to be removed when selecting using xpath.

[`XSLT`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt) should be used when you want to modify your xml - here in this case remove `Part` given that their `PartNumber` meet a specific condition.

The following xslt should achieve the same.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:variable name="invoiceNumber" select="substring-before(//Job/InvoiceNumber,'/')"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Part">
   <xsl:variable name="partNumber" select="substring-before(PartNumber,'/')"/>
   <xsl:if test="$partNumber = $invoiceNumber">
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
   </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The xslt works by using xpath `substring-before(PartNumber,'/')` which gives the number `23456` or `23459` before `/`

Then it is tested against the invoice number obtained from xpath `//Job/InvoiceNumber` in the `xsl:if` Only if the condition is satisfied, that `Part` is considered.

If you apply this xsl on your xml you will get the result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Job>
  <InvoiceNumber>23456/1.3</InvoiceNumber>
  <CompanyName>DummyJobOne</CompanyName>
  <CompanyNumber>7641</CompanyNumber>
  <Parts>
    <Part>
      <PartNumber>23456/1</PartNumber>
      <SourceEstimate>41847</SourceEstimate>
    </Part>
    <Part>
      <PartNumber>23456/2</PartNumber>
      <SourceEstimate>41847</SourceEstimate>
    </Part>
    <Part>
      <PartNumber>23456/3.2</PartNumber>
      <SourceEstimate>41847</SourceEstimate>
    </Part>
  </Parts>
</Job>
```

Comment: Thank you kjhughes & svasa.  These answers were perfect and gave me exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can select these parts,

```
  <Part> 
    <PartNumber>23456/1</PartNumber>  
    <SourceEstimate>41847</SourceEstimate> 
  </Part>  
  <Part> 
    <PartNumber>23456/2</PartNumber>  
    <SourceEstimate>41847</SourceEstimate> 
  </Part>  
  <Part> 
    <PartNumber>23456/3.2</PartNumber>  
    <SourceEstimate>41847</SourceEstimate> 
  </Part>
```

with this XPath expression,

```
//Part[substring-before(PartNumber,'/')=substring-before(../../InvoiceNumber, '/')]
```

but to reassemble them in the context of their ancestral elements, you'll need to go beyond selection to transformation.  XPath alone won't help, but XSLT would.